# jQuery Slide on Hover separate moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I made with some help some Style to move a Text in if Mouse is over. My Problem is that I can't separate the moves. If I am over of any Box than all Boxes get the effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.up-down').mouseover(function(){
        $('.default').stop().animate({
            height: 200    
        }, 200);                        
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('.default').stop().animate({
            height: 240 
        }, 200)    
    })
});
```

To see is here: http://jsfiddle.net/snHhN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the child of the currently hovered element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.up-down').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children('.default').stop().animate({
            height: 200    
        }, 200);                        
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).children('.default').stop().animate({
            height: 240 
        }, 200)    
    })
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/snHhN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `$('.default')` then ever element with the class default will be acted upon.

If .default is inside .up-down you could use

```
$(this).find('.default')
```

... and it will only act upon the correct element.